# apache https configuration problems

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, https, virtualhost

I am having problems configuring my RHEL box to accept HTTPS connections.  This is what I have so far:

My RHEL box sits in a DMZ on IP: 172.16.0.3 - I access the website by entering the IP into the browser. I do not have a DNS entry set up for this:

I have a Virtual Host set on the user directory:

```
/home/mywebapp
```

I have created a folder within here where I have created my certificate files.

```
/home/mywebapp/application/certs/
```

I have used this command to create the certificates:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -keyout 172.16.0.3.key -out 172.16.0.3.crt -nodes -subj  ‘/O=My Web App/OU=My Web App IT Dept/CN=172.16.0.3’
```

Within httpd.conf I have enabled named virtual hosting on 443:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443
```

I have configured my Virtual Hosts as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName 172.16.0.3
 ServerAlias 172.16.0.3 *.172.16.0.3
 DocumentRoot /home/mywebapp/public_html
 <Directory "/home/mywebapp/public_html">
     allow from all
     Options +Indexes
 </Directory>
 <Location />
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
     RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
 </Location>
 </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName 172.16.0.3
 ServerAlias 172.16.0.3 *.172.16.0.3
 DocumentRoot /home/mywebapp/public_html
 <Directory "/home/mywebapp/public_html">
     allow from all
     Options +Indexes
 </Directory>
 SSLEngine On
 SSLCertificateFile /home/mywebapp/application/certs/172.16.0.3.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/mywebapp/application/certs/172.16.0.3.key   
</VirtualHost>
```

This appears to work fine when visiting the site from the server browser eg "https://localhost", however trying to connect from a client browser via "https://172.16.0.3" fails to connect.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This question isn't really approriate to Stack Overflow, which is a Q&A forum for programming questions. Try posting it to Stack Overflow's companion site Server Fault (http://serverfault.com/), instead.

Comment: Will do next time.  Thanks for the heads up.  Anyway question answered by Satish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check `iptable` firewall
2. Disable `SELinux` if you can
3. Check whether port 80/443 is listen using `netstat -natp | grep -e 80 -e 443`
4. use `telnet 172.16.0.3 80` command from client to check it allowing to make connection.

Comment: Looks like I needed to add a line for port 443 in the Iptables - It works now.  Thank you